# How add reference authors in DESCRIPTION, in an R package?

Tags: r, cran

When sending my package to CRAN, I was asked to insert these reference fields, but I don't know where to insert exactly in DESCRIPTION, would anyone have an example?

"If there are references describing the methods in your package, please
add these in the description field of your DESCRIPTION file in the form
authors (year) doi:...
authors (year) arXiv:...
authors (year, ISBN:...)
or if those are not available: https:...
with no space after 'doi:', 'arXiv:', 'https:' and angle brackets for
auto-linking.
(If you want to add a title as well please put it in quotes: "Title")"

My only reference is this book:

Pellico Netto, S.; Brena, D. (1997). Inventario florestal. Curitiba: Universidade Federal do Parana, 316 p.

Comment: Do you have the DOI? I searched it during 15 minutes on Google, I didn't find it.

Comment: Stéphane, Thank you very much for your effort! It has no DOI, but it has two numbers of DDC (Dewey Decimal Classification) and UDC (Universal Decimal Classification), however I think this format is not accepted in Description, would you know?

Comment: As for the link, I have only one access to the pdf on Google Drive, however I believe that I cannot publish the book without the proper authorization of the authors. And because it is a little old book (1997), I did not find any link for sale.